# Various errors when using Hibernate as my JPA provider

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I'm giving a try to JPA, so I've followed a guide, and tried to do it by myself with Hibernate. I created an entity "testEntity" that just has two variables, and made a testing class with a main method to test it.

My connection pool has a JDBC connection that is already tested and working. I configured my persistence unit to use it. Check my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="PruebaswebPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider    </provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/nuevaConexion</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I use it in my test class:

```
  EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PruebaswebPU");
        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
        entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();

        testEntity ent = new testEntity();
        ent.setId(5l);
        ent.setNombre("Nombraco");

        entitymanager.persist(ent);
        entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();

        entitymanager.close();
        emfactory.close();
```

... but I get this bunch of errors:

```
may 06, 2016 12:52:26 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
may 06, 2016 12:52:26 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. 
may 06, 2016 12:52:26 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. 

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units   
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:99) 
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)     
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at testing.samplePersistence.main(samplePersistence.java:20)

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml. Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: El contenido del elemento 'persistence' no está completo. Se esperaba uno de '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":persistence-unit}'.
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:377)     
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:310)  
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:114) 
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:104)    
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:86) 
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:95)    ... 8 more 
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

edit:

A little screenshot of the auto-added libraries that Netbeans used for this project:

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Z4N.png)

Comment: The is a Problem in your persistence.XML. Maybe a not printable character in the first position

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem; the file hasn't anything at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `persistence.xml` is not complete. You may need some extra section. For more you can go through this [tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html).

**You have extra space also in your `persistence.xml`.**

First change in your `persistence.xml`

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider    </provider>
```

to

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Then Run. If any problem occurs, then inform me.

### UPDATE:

Would you please change the version as below:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: @PabloVicenteAlonso please check the update and let me know.

Comment: what is your hibernate and jpa version. Would you please add? @PabloVicenteAlonso

Comment: 4.3 and 2.1 I guess. Watch the image of the pre-added libraries that NetBeans managed to import to my project.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aziz781/1336488 Would you please compare with your code and some modification. hope it may help you.

Comment: Tried to use your code as template, but it doesn't work either... Same message than always.